# Wagtailstreamforms Fields Side-by-Side

Tags: python, forms, wagtail

Wagtailstreamforms is a great package to build forms very easily, it allows for fields to be stacked, but how do I choose fields to render side-by-side? Below is a picture of my desired outcome.

[image: Side-by-side fields]

Notice how the name and email fields and project timespan and budget fields are in the same row and are side-by-side. I want to add functionality where I can do this with any two types of fields, where I simply select the fields in the wagtailstreamforms form builder settings page.

How do I go about doing this?

---

**Edit: Some extra details.**

Right now wagtailstreamforms can only build forms with fields stacked one on top of the other. There is no functionality in the form builder page to create a grid system with form fields in multiple columns.

I want to add functionality where I can create a new field via the register decorator in wagtailstreamforms_fields.py, where the field will have two options, left and right, and each option will be a list of the available fields (excluding this one) so the user can create two fields to place side-by-side in two columns.

I have started to implement this by creating the field with the left and right options.

```
# wagtailstreamforms_fields.py

from django import forms
from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtailstreamforms import streamfield
from wagtailstreamforms.fields import BaseField, register

form_field_list_left = streamfield.FormFieldStreamBlock('form_two_columns_left')
form_field_list_right = streamfield.FormFieldStreamBlock('form_two_columns_left')

@register('two_columns')
class TwoColumns(BaseField):
    field_class = forms.MultiValueField
    widget = forms.MultiWidget
    icon = 'list-ul'
    label = 'Two Columns'

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('left', form_field_list_left),
            ('right', form_field_list_right),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)
```

[image: Field with left and right options]

The issue now is how do I access the left and right options in the templates?

If the two-column field works, I will be expanding this by creating a few other fields for three-columns and maybe even four-columns.

---

**Another edit: a different way to achieve this grid system.**

As I'm using Bootstrap CSS for my project, I can specify an extra option called `width` for each form, this will be a number from 1 to 12, 12 being full width.

I can then access this option in templates and append it to the CSS class of the container div, `col-{{ field.width }}`

This method allows more flexibility to the grid system's size, although it isn't as intuitive as having fields with preset column widths. I will be pursuing this approach in another StackOverflow post: [Adding additional information into each form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907666/adding-additional-information-into-each-form-field)

Comment: Could you please update the question with a bit more detail. a. Is this to change the form layout on the front end (on the public facing rendered page) or the admin (what logged in page editors see). b. maybe a mock up of what you would be hoping to see on the admin side.

Comment: I've added more details to the post

Answer (score 1):

Custom StreamField Block editing interfaces can be achieved in multiple ways, the simplest is to leverage the `form_classname` `meta` attribute and add css to suit.

### Step 1 - Define your `StructBlock`

- Here is a simple version of the screenshot you shared, the fields do not matter that much for this example.
- They key change is `form_classname = "struct-block column-layout"`, note that the `'struct-block'` must be included and the `'column-layout'` is what we will link the custom styles to.
- Note: You can also add the `form_classname` via a keyword argument for any `StructBlock` usage, you do not have to define your own class.

##### **my-app/blocks.py**

```py
from wagtail.core.blocks import CharBlock, StructBlock, TextBlock

# ...

class ProjectBlock(StructBlock):
    name = TextBlock()
    email = CharBlock(blank=True, required=False, label="e.g. joe@email.co")
    company = TextBlock()
    timespan = CharBlock(blank=True, required=False, label="e.g. 7 decades")
    budget = CharBlock(blank=True, required=False, label="$$$")

    class Meta:
        form_classname = "struct-block column-layout"
        icon = "fa-file"
```

### Step 2 - Add CSS (styles)

- These styles use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to show the fields as separate columns, you could also use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) if you wanted.
- The styles are scoped to devices above 970px, this is so that on smaller devices the rows will 'snap' back to being stacked.
- The key item to note here is the usage of `.column-layout` as defined in our `StructBlock`.
- There are specific styles for the `company` field, which is the field we want to show as full width.

##### **static/css/admin.css**

```css
@media (min-width: 970px) {
  .struct-block.column-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -1.5em;
  }

  .struct-block.column-layout > .field {
    min-width: calc(50% - 1.5em);
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }

  .struct-block.column-layout > .field + .field {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }

  .struct-block.column-layout > .field[data-contentpath="company"] {
    min-width: calc(100% - 1.5em);
  }
}
```

### Step 3 - Add CSS file to admin

- Ensure that the CSS file is loaded into the admin interface by leveraging the [Wagtail hooks](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css) system, the code for hooks must be added to a `wagtail_hooks.py` file.
- Remember to add `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static') ]` in your settings.py

##### **my-app/wagtail_hooks.py**

```py
from django.templatetags.static import static
from django.utils.html import format_html

from wagtail.core import hooks

# ...

@hooks.register("insert_editor_css")
def editor_css():
    return format_html('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{}">', static("css/admin.css"))
```

### Final Layout

- The final layout should look like below.

[image: multi column StructBlock layout example]

### Documentation

- This is a basic approach but should be enough to achieve what is needed, this could also be abstracted by creating a class that extends `StructBlock` and overrides some methods and default values, the documentation below has details about how to completely customise the form field rendering.
- [Customising the StreamField editing interfact](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock)
- [Inserting editor CSS](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however, this is how to create and display predefined forms. I am using the wagtailstreamforms package which allows forms to be created via StreamFields.