# Adding additional information into each form field

Tags: python, django, forms, wagtail, form-fields

I am using Django/Wagtail and the wagtailstreamforms package to build forms. Unfortunately you cannot add two fields side-by-side in the wagtailstreamforms form builder out of the box, so I am trying to add a functionality that allows the user to input an integer 1 to 12 (based on Bootstrap columns - col-1 to col-12) for each field and this number will be retrieved in the templates and will be used.

In the `wagtailstreamforms_fields.py` file, I've started to override the `CharField` model to add the extra `width` integer:

```
from django import forms
from wagtailstreamforms.fields import BaseField, register
from wagtail.core import blocks

class CustomCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

@register('singleline')
class Column_SingleLineTextField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomCharField

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options


    def get_formfield(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_formfield(block_value)
        return options
        

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)
```

This code adds the extra integer input for the `singleline` field in the wagtailstreamforms form builder page in Wagtail settings.

[image: Singleline width input]

Now the issue I'm facing is, I'm not able to retrieve the `width` parameter in the templates.

The `template/custom_form_block.html` file looks like this:

```
<form{% if form.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} class="row g-3 normal-form" action="{{ value.form_action }}" method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form.media }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}{{ hidden }}{% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {% include 'partials/custom_form_field.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">{{ value.form.submit_button_text }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the `templates/partials/custom_form_field.html` looks like this:

```
{% load form_tags %}

<div class="col-{{ field.col_width }}">
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.width }}
    <p>{% dict field %}</p>
    {% if field.help_text %}<p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }}</p>{% endif %}
    {{ field.errors }}
</div>
```

And the template tag in `templatetags/form_tags.py` contains:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def dict(this_object):
    return this_object.__dict__
```

And finally, the rendered page from the browser:

[image: Broswer output]

As you can see, the `dict` template tag returns all the parameters of the form and the `width` parameter isn't being passed.

How do I fix this and allow the `width` parameter to be read in the templates?

Answer (score 1):

**My crude but effective solution**

As I was unable to override the CharField model to add the additional parameter, `width`, I thought it would be easier to utilise an already existing parameter to pass the `width` value into the templates. For this approach, I will be using the `attrs` parameter to pass the `width` value into the HTML rendered instance of each form field, I will then use some jQuery to extract the value and add it to the class of the container div.

Starting with the singleline CharField, we need to override the field to allow the user to input a `width` value, my field override class looks like this:

```
@register('singleline')
class Column_SingleLineTextField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomSinglelineField
    icon = "pilcrow"
    label = "Text field (single line)"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)
```

Now we need to override the CharField class to set the `width` value as one of the attributes in `attrs`:

```
class CustomSinglelineField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

**The whole code (`wagtailstreamforms_fields.py`)**

I have also added a `placeholder` option to some of the applicable fields, a `rows` attribute option for the multiline field, as well as the `width` option:

```
from django import forms
from wagtailstreamforms.fields import BaseField, register
from wagtail.core import blocks

class CustomSinglelineField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width, 'placeholder': self.placeholder})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomMultilineField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.rows = kwargs.pop('rows')
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.Textarea(attrs={'col_width': self.width, 'rows': self.rows, 'placeholder': self.placeholder})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomDateField(forms.DateField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomDatetimeField(forms.DateField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomEmailField(forms.EmailField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.EmailInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width, 'placeholder': self.placeholder})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomURLField(forms.URLField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.URLInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width, 'placeholder': self.placeholder})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomNumberField(forms.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.URLInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width, 'placeholder': self.placeholder})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomDropdownField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomRadioField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.RadioSelect(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomCheckboxesField(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.SelectMultiple(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomCheckboxField(forms.BooleanField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomSinglefileField(forms.FileField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class CustomMultifileField(forms.FileField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.width = kwargs.pop('width')
        self.widget = forms.widgets.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'col_width': self.width,"multiple": True})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)


@register('singleline')
class Column_SingleLineTextField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomSinglelineField
    icon = "pilcrow"
    label = "Text field (single line)"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'placeholder': block_value.get('placeholder')})
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('placeholder', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('multiline')
class MultiLineTextField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomMultilineField
    icon = "form"
    label = "Text field (multiple lines)"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        options.update({'rows': block_value.get('rows')})
        options.update({'placeholder': block_value.get('placeholder')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('placeholder', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ('rows', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Height of field", max_value=100, min_value=1, default=10, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('date')
class DateField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomDateField
    icon = "date"
    label = "Date field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('datetime')
class DateTimeField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomDatetimeField
    icon = "time"
    label = "Time field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('email')
class EmailField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomEmailField
    icon = "mail"
    label = "Email field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        options.update({'placeholder': block_value.get('placeholder')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('placeholder', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('url')
class URLField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomURLField
    icon = "link"
    label = "URL field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        options.update({'placeholder': block_value.get('placeholder')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('placeholder', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('number')
class NumberField(BaseField):
    field_class = forms.DecimalField
    label = "Number field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        options.update({'placeholder': block_value.get('placeholder')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock([
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('help_text', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('required', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
            ('default_value', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('placeholder', blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
            ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
        ], icon=self.icon, label=self.label)

@register('dropdown')
class DropdownField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomDropdownField
    icon = "arrow-down-big"
    label = "Dropdown field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("label", blocks.CharBlock()),
                ("help_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("required", blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
                ("empty_label", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("choices", blocks.ListBlock(blocks.CharBlock(label="Option"))),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ],
            icon=self.icon,
            label=self.label,
        )

@register('radio')
class RadioField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomRadioField
    icon = "radio-empty"
    label = "Radio buttons"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("label", blocks.CharBlock()),
                ("help_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("required", blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
                ("choices", blocks.ListBlock(blocks.CharBlock(label="Option"))),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ],
            icon=self.icon,
            label=self.label,
        )

@register('checkboxes')
class CheckboxesField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomCheckboxesField
    icon = "tick-inverse"
    label = "Checkboxes"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("label", blocks.CharBlock()),
                ("help_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("required", blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
                ("choices", blocks.ListBlock(blocks.CharBlock(label="Option"))),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ],
            icon=self.icon,
            label=self.label,
        )

@register('checkbox')
class CheckboxField(BaseField):
    field_class = forms.BooleanField
    icon = "tick-inverse"
    label = "Checkbox field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("label", blocks.CharBlock()),
                ("help_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("required", blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ],
            icon=self.icon,
            label=self.label,
        )

@register('singlefile')
class SingleFileField(BaseField):
    field_class = CustomSinglefileField
    icon = "doc-full-inverse"
    label = "File field"

    def get_options(self, block_value):
        options = super().get_options(block_value)
        options.update({'width': block_value.get('width')})
        return options

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("label", blocks.CharBlock()),
                ("help_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("required", blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ],
            icon=self.icon,
            label=self.label,
        )

@register('multifile')
class MultiFileField(BaseField):
    field_class = forms.FileField
    icon = "doc-full-inverse"
    label = "Files field"

    def get_form_block(self):
        return blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("label", blocks.CharBlock()),
                ("help_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("required", blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False)),
                ('width', blocks.IntegerBlock(help_text="Width of field, 1 to 12, 12 is full width.", max_value=12, min_value=1, default=12, required=True)),
            ],
            icon=self.icon,
            label=self.label,
        )
```

**Now the templates**

The `templates/custom_form_block.html` is unchanged and looks like the following:

```
<form{% if form.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} class="row g-3 normal-form" action="{{ value.form_action }}" method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form.media }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}{{ hidden }}{% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {% include 'partials/custom_form_field.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">{{ value.form.submit_button_text }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the `templates/partials/custom_form_field.html` has all the changes and looks like the following:

```
<div class="field-column-id_{{ value.form.slug }}_{{ field.name }}">
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}<p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }}</p>{% endif %}
    {{ field.errors }}
</div>

<script>
    var col_width = $(".field-column-id_{{ value.form.slug }}_{{ field.name }} #id_{{ field.name }}").attr("col_width")
    $(".field-column-id_{{ value.form.slug }}_{{ field.name }}").addClass("col-"+col_width);
    
    // Set the "None" placeholders as ""
    var placeholder = $(".field-column-id_{{ value.form.slug }}_{{ field.name }} #id_{{ field.name }}").attr("placeholder")
    if (placeholder == "None") {
        $(".field-column-id_{{ value.form.slug }}_{{ field.name }} #id_{{ field.name }}").attr("placeholder", "")
    }
</script>
```

I am setting the parent div for each field as `field-column-id_{{ value.form.slug }}_{{ field.name }}`, this way if we have multiple forms with fields of the same name on the same page, there wouldn't be any conflicts as each form will have a unique slug.

The jQuery retrieved the `col_width` HTML attribute that we set as the `width` option and will append it to `col-` and set it as the parent div's class.

By default, if we don't set a value in the 'placeholder' option, wagtailstreamforms sets this option as 'None'. We don't want an empty placeholder to be displayed as 'None' in the HTML so we have a jQuery script that replaces `None` with an empty string. This will work for the most part but this functionality breaks when the user wants the placeholder to actually be set to `None`.

This solution works for the most part, but in my honest opinion, I'm not very proud of it as I think this is inefficient and hacky.

Comment: It seems we're trying to solve this problem at the same time. I asked this yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917646/wagtail-adding-css-class-or-placeholder-to-form-builder-fields/68920368?noredirect=1#comment121829153_68920368) and it works for regular wagtail contrib forms, although I wanted to use wagtailstreamforms as well. I can see you opened an issue on the wagtailstreamforms git repo, hopefully someone gets back to you with a more robust solution. Seems weird that this functionality doesn't exist considering how useful and simple it is. Thanks for this write up anyway

Comment: Ah, and I'm guessing you've come across the issue I opened (#180) and have bumped it, thanks for that :) - Let's see what comes up on the git issue I opened, until then I'll be using my `attrs` solution.